# Users per applications in MySQL

Tags: mysql, administration

I work with a few applications at the company I work for. I would like to know what should be a better choice:

1. create each person a user y MySQL (configured through an ODBC)
2. create a user per application and use the same user in all ODBCs through the whole company?

What do you think will be the advantages or drawbacks?

Comment: This needs more information to be answered well. What kinds of applications are those - web apps, desktop apps?

Comment: I'm sorry for poor details, they are some RIA(unipaas) and web apps. and it is a small company (around 125 employees)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a user per application.  If your company is of any size, you will quickly find yourself spending all your time creating and destroying MySQL users.

It is better to maintain the user logins in a database for authentication on application startup, and then the application it's own connection/user to MySQL (which it also uses to authenticate the user).

Then limit all your security based on the user rights that you design in your user table, instead of relying on MySQL to keep people in check.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd better creating a user (with few privileges, the ones required and no more) for every application.
Then create (for every application) a superuser) that maintains it.